# Unable to make background scroll with page on mobile phones

Tags: html, css

My css:

```
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url('image.jpg');
background-size:100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-attachement: fixed;
```

This works fine on browsers, but when view it on mobile phones - tested on Nokia Lumia and Samsung S2 using latest Firefox version.

I'm talking about viewing the site in desktop view. Is there a different line of code needed to achieve this?

Comment: You may need to give a bit more code than supplied. but `position:fixed` might be your solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I changed it so background-size was:

```
background-size:cover;
```

In my mobile media query. This may give you your desired effect assuming your background image is not a tile.

Answer (score 0):

Only small thing you are missing, just add thi in your code.

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Hope this works.